# Align right content in div element

Tags: html, css

I have searched around but can't find a working solution to this. How to horizontally align any content to the right, not just text, within a div element. For example:

```
<div>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</div>
```

If I add a `max-width` to the div element, then it's no problem using something like `margin: 0 0 0 auto`, but this does not work with `with: 100%` which is what I need. I have been away from this web game for some time, and I had some expectation that CSS had become a bit more friendly since HTML5, but it's still a pain to work with, although it has brought some improved features.

And I don't need any backward-compatible solution, unless that's the only one of cause. If a browser don't have proper HTML5/CSS3 support, then to bad.

**EDIT:**

Well if I do `div > input { margin: 0 0 0 auto }` it works, but I am guessing that this will provide issues if I have more than one element in this div, so not the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a float:right on the input. This is a great article on floats that I constantly go back to: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

```
.rightAlign {
  float:right;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7zutppme/)

Comment: Okay, still if I have more content inside than a single input, it will be ordered differently?

Comment: Well it sort of works, but content breaks out of the div and is placed below it. If you add a border to the div you can see that. It also does not align well with the <main> element's background color as it breaks out of that element as well.

Comment: Never mind your great article had the answer. Could not get any clearFix to work, but setting the div's overflow to auto worked fine. No fancy :after clearfix. Thanks, I will read this article thoroughly.